# How do you execute cron job every 5 minutes?

Tags: java

```
JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(FirstJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("*/10 * * * * ?")).build();

Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler1.start();
scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

JobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.newJob(SecondJob.class).withIdentity("job2", "group2").build();

Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger2", "group2")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(new CronExpression("0/7 * * * * ?"))).build();

Scheduler scheduler2 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler2.start();
scheduler2.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);

Thread.sleep(100000);

scheduler1.shutdown();
scheduler2.shutdown();
```

I am trying to execute a cron job every 5 minutes of an hour, but it's not executing on time. I think that the time expression is wrong.

How do you set the time expression for a 1, 5 minute job and a 2 for 1 hour job?

Comment: You can use the online cron job expression builder [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Comment: @TheLostMind  please tell me where am doing wrong because when i set that my job is Executing but i have to set job 1 for 5 minute and job 2 for 1 hour

Comment: 0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? * so for 5 minute it should like this right please wait let me check

Comment: @TheLostMind thanx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For job 1, 5 minute, you can use:

```
*/5 * * * * ?
```

Because the first field is for minutes. If you specify * in this field, it runs every minutes. If you specify */5 in the 1st field, it runs every 5 minutes as shown above.

For job 2, 1 hour, you can use:

```
0 */1 * * *
```

Because the second field is for hours. If you specify * in this field, it runs every hour. If you specify */5 in the 2nd field, it runs every 5 hours as shown above.

Not related with cron but your code seems to be missing to pass expression as to TheLostMind comment.

**Correct sentence For job 1:**

```
Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(new CronExpression("*/10 * * * * ?"))).build();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But it stop after one time Excute can u please tel me what i am doing wrong

Comment: why my job Stop after 2 time Excute

Comment: @MhanazSyed , because you only sleep 100 seconds and you shut down your schedule tasks.

Comment: Thread.sleep method accept milliseconds parameter and you only set 100000, so it equal 100 seconds. Think about it and try not to shut down your scheduler tasks.

Comment: thanx @Ye Win i got Solution

Comment: then we should remove 
   // Thread.sleep(100000); also right?

Comment: it's up to you, but you need to know when you will stop your scheduler in code.

Comment: if you don't want to stop, it's ok, but your task will always run as to your cron expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127765/discussion-between-mhanaz-syed-and-ye-win).

Answer (score 0):

To run a cron job every 5 min, you can use: `0 */5 * * * ?`[image]

In above reply the cron job expression shared, run the cron job every 5 secs not mins, you can also verify from the url http://www.cronmaker.com/?0