# SchedulingConfigurer/CronTrigger regex is not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, spring, scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am using Spring SchedulingConfigurer and CronTrigger to trigger a job at every 5 minutes but code is not working as expected.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Scheduler task is running: " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("* */5 * * * *");
                return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
}
```

**I am following below regex rules as mentioned in spring doc.**
"0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.

"*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
"0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
"0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
"0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight

I tried below but no luck.
[How do you execute cron job every 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521416/how-do-you-execute-cron-job-every-5-minutes)
[Create a regular expression for Cron statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203122/create-a-regular-expression-for-cron-statement)
[Create a regular expression for Cron statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203122/create-a-regular-expression-for-cron-statement/19046939)

Comment: Maybe http://www.cronmaker.com can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution with the help of [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com).

```
@Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Scheduler task is running: " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ?");
                return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
```