# Spring Scheduling CronTrigger CronExpression overriding for next() to consider unexpected holidays

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a large number of tasks running on cron schedules, using Spring Boot's scheduling libraries. However, I want to cause these schedules to **not** run on specific days (e.g. a nation strike or a government election).

He have a database containing such calendars, which are kept up-to-date. My intention was to override [CronExpression#next()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html#next(T)) by first running `super.next(temporal)` then comparing the result on a check against my database and then returning a modified `Temporal` if the `super.next()` would result on a run on a public holiday. I would *assume*, that my `CronTrigger` would obey the next run according to my overriden `CronExpression`.

What I cannot figure out is where `CronExpression` is used? The `CronExpression` API doc says;

> See Also: CronTrigger

The [CronTrigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) API description says;

> Trigger implementation for cron expressions. Wraps a CronExpression.

However, all of this API's constructors use `String`. Why not `CronExpression`? So, where is the connection between these two classes? (How can I have `CronTigger` use an overridden `CronExpression`?).

The only alternative that I can see is that I create `abstract` class for `Runnable`, then have it's `run()` call my database. After which, I re-code my existing tasks to `extend` this `abstract` class's `run()` and `return` immediately on a public holiday, otherwise run as before.

Comment: The documentation says it all `Wraps a CronExpression`. It is used internally. If you want to do something else, write your own trigger implementation.

Comment: It seems like I need to use this https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html  . Example usage here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711988/schedulingconfigurer-crontrigger-regex-is-not-working-as-expected

Comment: No you don't. As that is for onetime scheduling, without a proper trigger implementation it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

A crude example based on seconds (not holidays) which has a schedule of every 5 seconds, but skips 10, 20 etc (inspired this post [SchedulingConfigurer/CronTrigger regex is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711988/schedulingconfigurer-crontrigger-regex-is-not-working-as-expected))

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
        
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Running: " + LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            
            static final String CRON_EXP = "0/5 * * * * *";
            
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                System.err.println("Next Execution Time >>>");
                
                CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(CRON_EXP);
                Date nextRegular = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
                
                if (isHoliday(nextRegular)) {
                    CronExpression cronExpression = CronExpression.parse(CRON_EXP);
                    LocalDateTime next = cronExpression.next(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5)); // should be 00:00:01 of next non-holiday.
                    nextRegular = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(next);
                }
                return nextRegular;
            }
            
            private boolean isHoliday(Date d) {
                LocalDateTime ldt = d.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
                return ldt.getSecond() % 10 == 0; // should do database look-up here.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`Date nextExecutionTime()` is deprecated in Spring Framework 6 in favour of `Instant nextExecution()`, so this answer is for Spring Framework 5.